# If I disable the 5GHz radio on my router will it improve my 2.4GHz performance or range?

Tags: router, ieee-802.11

I am having an ASUS RT-AC53 dual-band router having 3 antennas.
Currently, it is emitting both the 2.4GHz and 5GHz wifi radios.
I am just curious if I disable the 5GHz radio will it anyway improve the performance or signal range or availability of the 2.4GHz signal?
Is there any possibility for the antenna which is getting used for emitting the 5GHz signal, will instead be used for 2.4GHz?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

It should make no difference, as it should normally behave like a switch and only send the packet out of the correct channel.